# Can't access mail value in facebook sdk although permission

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Hi I have a problem with the Facebook API although I am asking for the permission to get the email I can't get the mail value, what do I do wrong? Here my code:

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  'cookie' => false
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();

if ($fbuser) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $FBUSER = $facebook->api('/me');
    $FBUSER1 = $facebook->api('/me');
    print_r($FBUSER1);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    print_r($e);
    $USER=false;
  }
}
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope"=>"email, publish_actions"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few days ago I was coding a similar login/authorization bit of my app and I had similar results until I properly ordered the flow steps.

From your snippet it looks like you print the $fbuser array before the user actually grants the extended permissions to your app. Let's imagine you were doing some tests with your own account being logged in to facebook: you might have authorized the app once with the basic permission and now it returns these basic data from your account (with no "email" as it belongs to the extended perms).

More code could help to better understand but I would still double check that:
1. the page/popup coming from the FB getLoginURL() method is shown and the user accepts both to login (if not) and to authorize the extended permissions if needed.
2. the return_uri code on your website is ready to catch any data coming from the previous step (eg. print the user details).

Watchout as I see from your code that the return_uri is not defined.

Comment: yes the appId and secret are correct they get me to the try catch part and i get all the information i need the only problem is that in the array i don't get the mail, i just called it twice because i tried different other request that could give me the mail but none of them worked...

Answer (score 0):

If you send request without access_token, you will get short field set without email and some different fields.